# Error deploying feature SP2013

Tags: c#, sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2013

I've created a Feature and I want it to be activated when installed.
This is the code:

```
public override void FeatureInstalled(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
    SPWebTemplateCollection existingWebTemps = web.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1033);
    Collection<SPWebTemplate> newWebTemps = new Collection<SPWebTemplate>();        
    for (int i = 0; i < existingWebTemps.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!existingWebTemps[i].Title.ToLower().Contains("blog"))
        {
            newWebTemps.Add(existingWebTemps[i]);
        }
    }
    web.SetAvailableWebTemplates(newWebTemps, 1033);
    web.Update();

    string fID = "aeb3aa40-8a42-4577-bed2-a0e65eff8b04";
    Guid gfID = new Guid(fID);
    SPFeatureCollection featatv = web.Features;
    Boolean control = true;
    foreach (SPFeature myfeat in featatv)
    {
        if (myfeat.DefinitionId == gfID)
        {
            control = false;
        }
    }
    if (control == true)
    {
        web.Features.Add(gfID);
    }

    web.Dispose();
}
```

When I deploy I get the error:

Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I can't understand why I'm getting this error.
Any thoughts on why?
Thank you!

Comment: did you find anything in event log ??

Comment: @SigarDave I searched the logs but couldn't find anything useful  - the logs I saw were at (...)\15\LOGS.  Am I looking in the right place? I'm new to SharePoint, please bear with me! :)  In VS there's nothing besides the error message.

Comment: Yes you are at the right place

Comment: Try this thing  ,set the feature property “Always Force Install” to  true. let me know the outcome

Comment: With Force Install the feature is deployed but not activated as it should be. As for the logs, what log should I look at? Thank you!

Comment: Feature instaaled but not activated automatically? in that case you have to change the property of feature to make it activate automatically

Comment: I have it working now. The question I had was with a web scope feature but then I changed the code to work on a farm scope and when installed it gets activated automatically. Thank you!

Comment: Oh k thanks for sharing the solution.. does my aboce comments or Answer help in getting the answer?

Comment: @SigarDave yes tahnk you!